# Does Snowflake support case insensitive where clause filter similar to SQL Server

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am migrating SQL code to snowflake and during migration i found that by default snowflake is comparing varchar field (ex. select 1 where 'Hello' = 'hello') incorrectly. To solve this problem i set collation 'en-ci' at account level. However now i am not able to use REPLACE like crucial function.

Is it possible in snowflake to do case insensitive varchar comparison (without mentioning collation explicitly or using UPPER function every time) and still use replace function?

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

you can compare the test with a case intensive match via [ILIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ilike.html)

```
select 1 where 'Hello' ilike 'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

regexp_replace is your friend, it allows for 'i' parameter that stands for "ignore case":
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html

For example you can do something like that:

```
select regexp_replace('cats are grey, cAts are Cats','cats','dogs',1,0,'i');
```

I've assumed the default values for position and occurrence but those can also be adjusted

And you can still do comparison (also based on regexp, aka "RLIKE"):
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/rlike.html

Comment: regexp_replace still generate error "SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 7 Function REGEXP_REPLACE does not support collation."

Comment: because you need to remove collation, then you will be able to use regexp_replace and rlike.

other than that you can wait - the number of functions supporting collation keeps growing...

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake supports [COLLATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/collate.html):

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 'Hello' = 'hello' COLLATE 'en-ci';
-- 1

SELECT 'Hello' = 'hello'
      ,'Hello' = 'hello' COLLATE 'en-ci';
```

Output:

[image]

---

The collation could be setup at account/database/schema/table level with parameter [DEFAULT_DDL_COLLATION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#default-ddl-collation):

> Sets the default collation used for the following DDL operations:
>
> - CREATE TABLE
> - ALTER TABLE … ADD COLUMN
>
> Setting this parameter forces all subsequently-created columns in the affected objects (table, schema, database, or account) to have the specified collation as the default, unless the collation for the column is explicitly defined in the DDL.